# Getting a VLAN IP address

Tags: linux, windows, cisco, linux-networking, vlan

**is there anyway to get a static IP address from a VLAN port on a CISCO switch** ?.

**what I'm looking for is a software weather it's a Linux or windows software when I plug Ethernet cable from my laptop into the VLAN port in the CISCO switch ,it will identify the the port and the assigned static IP address to that VLAN port .**

we have more 700 access points connected to many switches ,many of these access points there label removed ,so when I go to troubleshoot an access point I only have the IP address,If know the IP address I can match it with my AP database and I can identify the Access point label and fix it back.

Comment: Rather than unplugging 700 devices start from the comfort of your desk and follow the instructions from this answer: http://serverfault.com/a/39379/37681 to associate switch port-number with the VLAN number, MAC address and ip-address of the connected device

Comment: I'm not going to unplugging 700 devices,I only get emails regarding an AP that goes down the info I get is AP label and IP address,but If the AP label was removed it will be really hard to now the AP. the best way is to get IP address that has been assigned to that VLAN port .I don't have access to the switch .

Comment: If you don't have access to the switch, how do you expect to get this information?

Comment: there must me a way of sniffing the IP address some contractors have a device that can detect the IP address by just connecting the RJ35 to the switch,contacting the support company for the network infrastructure is very annoying process they replay me after 1 day after I send the email. it's so annoying to handle this with emails I'm sure there is a way .

Comment: Try sniffing for CDP packets from the switch. At the very least you can get the switch port.

Comment: @BrandonXavier may I know which software can do that ?

Comment: Osama are you looking for assign the same IP to the same device (AP) every time its join the network ??????

Comment: @Gadeliow nope that's not what I'm looking for,a windows or Linux application that can detect the Gi port no and IP address for a vlan in a CISCO switch without buying expensive  3000$ Fluke device to do that.

Comment: are you try CDP client windows app

Comment: @Gadeliow no because I have no access to the cisco device because it's supported by third party vendor they are responsible for the support they are based in Malaysia and India there response is not that fast so I can't count on the support I need faster solution .

Comment: you don't need any access ya OS just run it

Comment: @Gadeliow that's sounds grate can you suggest me any app ?

Comment: cisco cdp client http://sourceforge.net/projects/cdp4win/

Comment: welcome any time i just post it as answer

Comment: Or a simple tcpdump or wireshark `tcpdump -nn -v -i eth0 -s 1500 -c 1 'ether[20:2] == 0x2000'`

Comment: @BrandonXavier I will give it a try .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use cisco cdp client 
[cdp client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cdp4win/)
which is A free simple tool to find out connected Cisco switch port information (with CDP enabled on the Cisco switch)